# Does List<T>.Last() enumerate the collection?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, linq-to-objects

Considering the boundaries of a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) are known, does `.Last()` enumerate the collection?

I ask this because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) says that it is defined by `Enumerable` (in which case it *would* need to enumerate the collection)

If it *does* enumerate the collection then I can simply access the last element by index (as we know the `.Count` of a `List<T>`) but it seems silly to have to do this....

Comment: If you know you have a `List<T>`, then just access the last element the fast way, without relying on possible non-documented optimizations in `Last()`. (It so happens that `Last()` *does* check to see if the receiver implements `IList<T>`, and optimizes that case.)

Comment: @dlev yes, as I mentioned I am aware I can do this... I'm asking particularly about the implementation of `.Last`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the implementation checks for `List<T>` and access the last element by index if possible.

Comment: A lot of the LINQ extensions check for indexed types as an optimization. I wouldn't be surprised if Last() did the same. Of course, this would be implementation-defined and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is you shouldn't *rely* on the behavior, since it isn't documented as such (even though it *does* perform the optimization.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it does not enumerate it. It first checks if the enumerable can be casted to an `IList<T>`(which Array and `List<T>` implement), then the index will be used directly without enumeration.

[`Enumerable.Last`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,75722fd194dc2e0e) source:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) {
                TSource result;
                do {
                    result = e.Current;
                } while (e.MoveNext());
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Side-note: only single dimensional [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks) implement `IList<T>`, which makes sense.

Comment: Your code provided demonstrated that **no**, it does not cause an enumeration of the `List<T>`... but your first line says "Yes" ;-)

Comment: @MatthewPK It's "Yes, it will iterate the whole enumerable if it's not an `IList<T>`" A little confusing, but correct.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Eleven year old comment cleanup effort :)